# Posting to the same form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, form-submit

I'm trying to build a search form in Laravel such that when a user presses the search button, all the contacts matching the search criteria are displayed on the same page.

Below is my form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/directory', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone number">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Enter Email - leave blank if you are not sure">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-u btn-u-green">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <li>{{$user->firstname}} {{$user->lastname}}</li>

        @endforeach
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The screenshot below gives a pictorial view of my form:

[image: search page]

My route is defined as follow:

```
Route::get('/directory', 'UsersController@filter');
```

Now, whenever I press the search button, I am getting a `MethodNotFound exception`.

What I really want to do is to show the search results below the search button.

**Edit ..**

Everything is working fine now except for one thing.

I'm displaying the data in my view (getting the list of all the users on my page which match the search criteria) but the for loop is not getting executed.

```
<li>Count of users = {{ $users->count() }}</li>
<li>{{$users->first()->lastname}}</li>
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

So: while I can see the count and the *lastname* of the first user in the resultant array of records, the foreach loop is not getting executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel routes are bound to the form METHOD, so you need to create also a POST route:

```
Route::post('/directory', 'UsersController@filter');
```

You also need to add names to your form fields:

```
name="lastname"
```

for

```
<input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
```

And for all the others.

A controller method to handle that query could look like this:

```
<?php

class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function filter() 
    {
        $users = User::query();

        if (Input::has('lastname'))
        {
            $users->where('lastname', Input::get('lastname'))
        }

        if (Input::has('phone'))
        {
            $users->where('phone', Input::get('phone'))
        }

        return View::make('your.view')
                ->with('userCount', $users->count());
                ->with('users', $users->get());
    }

}
```

And in your view you can just:

```
<li>Count of users = {{$userCount}}</li>

@foreach ($users as $user)
    <li>
        {{ $user->id }} - {{$user->lastname}}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks @Antonio .. I am not getting the exception now but the records are not getting populated... can you please help me with that..

Comment: To help you with data insertion, you'll have to show us your controller.

Comment: Hi Antonio, I guess I was wrong. I can display the data but i really dont know why the foreach loop is not getting executed. Please see the  orginal post for latest updates..

Comment: Views are not supposed to know much about your data, send everything you need to render to them, like I did with count() in this last edit.

Comment: Isn't `Rout::any()` better in these situations??

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Laravel that you want to use `get` method for submitting a form to the server. otherwise, Laravel will use `post` method by default.

Try the following:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/directory', 'method' => 'get', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}

                                                        ^^^
```